# "He found the bicycle that he had lost yesterday." Past perfect with yesterday?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-constructions

> He found the bicycle that he had lost **yesterday**.

Is this sentence correct? If so, which is the intended meaning:

1. He lost the bicycle yesterday and he found it  after that.
2. He lost the bicycle someday before yesterday and he found it yesterday.

Sometimes, past perfect is so confusing to non-native speaker, so which meaning does it have, 1 or 2?

Comment: Did you write the sentence? Which meaning did you intend to convey?

Comment: No, this is not my sentence. I saw this question on a Q & A (English studying) website in Korea.

Comment: Past Perfect always refers to an event before the Past Simple, that means it goes even deeper in time. So he lost the bicycle and later he found it, eventually it happened after he had lost it. "Yesterday" refers to the time the bicycle was lost not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English has some restrictions on [word order](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_order) and has rules about the order and position adverbs occur in. (The ordering is based on the meaning of the adverbs.)

Moving words out of the expected order, termed [anastrophe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anastrophe), can give information about the intended meaning, but unfortunately this was not done.

The sentence could have been written as

> **Today** he found the bicycle that he had lost yesterday.

If so it would mean that *finding* occurred *today* and that *losing* occurred *yesterday*. (Note it would **not** have the same meaning as the original sentence in this case!)

This change clarifies the meaning of *yesterday* because it forces us to think of *yesterday* as part of the [bound relative clause](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause).

However we cannot know for certain what the writer means because they didn’t include that information.

In summary *yesterday* could be either inside or outside of the relative clause *that he had lost*.

If inside then *yesterday* helps describe the bicycle.  Outside it describes the act of finding the bicycle.